# Execute Bash Script After Git Post-Receive Hook executes

Tags: bash, git

I have a bash script on my test server that will export my wordpress db, rsync the db to the prod server, and git push all of my files to prod sever.

Within the prod server's git repo I have a git `post-receive` hook correctly configured.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Receive Git Push from Test
git --work-tree=/home/username/public_html --git-dir=/home/username/public_html/git/production-site.git checkout -f
```

Within the working tree directory (WordPress directory) on the prod server I also have a bash script that will import the newly uploaded db.  `/home/username/public_html/db-import-script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

#bunch of commands
...
...
...
```

**Question:**
How can I automatically execute the db import script immediately following a git push?

**troubleshooting:**
inside of `post-receive`, I have tried using an absolute paths to execute the script, no luck

```
#!/bin/bash
#Receive Git Push from Test
git --work-tree=/home/username/public_html --git-dir=/home/username/public_html/git/production-site.git checkout -f

#execute script with absolute path
/home/username/public_html/db-import-script.sh
```

`db-import-script.sh` does not execute.  **NOTE:** this script must remain located in the Wordpress directory b/c it uses wp-cli commands for various actions.

any tips?

Comment: Personally, I'd set this up as a systemd service so you can use `systemctl start` to trigger it. That way you get logs available in journald, and all of systemd's various features for deciding how you want to handle failures, trigger notifications on successes, or whatever else.

Comment: That said, instead of just saying "no luck" -- show us _how your code failed_. If you don't _know_ how it failed, then you should add enough logging that you understand the narrow, specific problem you want us to help with in enough detail that you can actually help us help you with that problem :)

Comment: ...a good place to start towards that end is to add something like `exec 2>>/tmp/post-receive.log; PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'; set -x` to the top of your script (below the shebang), and then to review `/tmp/post-receive.log`. (Ideally change the log location to somewhere that only the user this is running as can write, instead of using `/tmp`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx for feedback and the super handy script log command.  While I am normally a big fan of details. in this scenario, however, I don't see how the additional detail paints a clearer picture than before.  I have script.sh in a directory and it needs to run whenever post-receive is executed.  pretty straightforward.  The above additional details that I have added don't add much t the original post.

Comment: I agree, the added details don't add much. But then, you haven't added the specific details I asked for -- an xtrace log. If provided, that would allow readers to understand _how_ and _why_ your original code failed, instead of just "no luck" or "doesn't execute".

Comment: If the log command doesn't produce a file, the next step is to strace the parent process (or, perhaps easier, use a tool like sysdig to trace the entire operating system). But we can go there after it's confirmed to be the case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Any tips for getting the logging working? I created a  /home/username/script-logs directory.  and changed the above to `exec 2>>/home/username/script-logs/post-receive.log; PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE##*/}:$LINENO+'; set -x`  but no luck ;-)

Comment: If it helps I am on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It sounds like you're at the point where I would be asking sysdig to trace `git-receive-pack` and its subprocesses.

Comment: I this logging snippet to work inside my db import script located in the wordpress directory `exec  5>> /home/adminwph/script-logs/test-push-db-import.log; BASH_XTRACEFD="5"; PS4='$LINENO: '; set -x;` . This log just confirms what I already know.  My db-import.sh script works.  My git push works.  'post-receive' cannot execute the script... an example of how to call the script my save multiple days of time.

Comment: There's a reason I suggested redirecting stderr instead of setting up a non-default `BASH_XTRACEFD`: stderr is where the shell (and standard UNIX commands) logs failures. So if you're logging stderr and the execve() to start the script is in fact failing, an error message explaining that failure will show up in your log. Using a non-default fd defeats that benefit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your snippet produced no output at all from `post-receive`, no from `db-import.sh`, so common sense, I researched and found a snippet that produced output.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I use e.g. [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) and on server one has to simply copy a script in `post-receive.d/` folder. The `post-receive` hook *(see below and you may use it as a template)* will scan this folder and execute scripts in it.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# AUTO GENERATED BY GITEA, DO NOT MODIFY
data=$(cat)
exitcodes=""
hookname=$(basename $0)
GIT_DIR=${GIT_DIR:-$(dirname $0)/..}

for hook in ${GIT_DIR}/hooks/${hookname}.d/*; do
  test -x "${hook}" && test -f "${hook}" || continue
  echo "${data}" | "${hook}"
  exitcodes="${exitcodes} $?"
done

for i in ${exitcodes}; do
  [ ${i} -eq 0 ] || exit ${i}
done
```

Comment: Note the guidance in the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) about questions that "...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem". If we don't know why the OP is having a problem with their existing scripts, how can we say with certainty that any other script will behave differently?

Comment: @m19v  thanks for the feedback.  Not quite *getting* your response.  Are you saying that I should create `post-receive.d` directory, replace my current `post-receive`  script with your gitea script, then place my bash script into the newly created `post-receive.d` directory.  1. I appreciate the response, but this seems like overkill.  2.  my `db-import-script.sh` must be located in the WordPress directory b/c it uses wp-cli commands to things.

Answer (score 0):

kiss rule... (keep it simple stupid)

rather than spending days trying to learn sysdig well enough to trace a process that I have never previously heard of and it subprocesses.  (no offence intended Charles, just need to actually get tasks done. Your bash debug-log snippet highly useful)

and rather than creating some *git / gitea hybrid*  (no offence @m19v, I did try your solution, but didn't work)

knowing that production server `db-import.sh` worked properly and that my test server git push / db upload `push.sh` worked properly.

My final solution was to leave the production server's `post-receive` properly configured and to.... remotely execute my `db-import.sh` script via ssh directly within the directory in which it needs to be executed.

In a nutshell, I added this to the end of `push.sh` script on my test server:

```
#Remotely execute db import
ssh -p22 -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa username@1233.456.789.12  'cd public_html && bash' << EOF
./db-import.sh
EOF
```

Bang problem solved...